# updating a log file online and perform some actions

Tags: c#

Lets say we have a log file (preferably a txt file) available in the web server. How can we put it online and update it constantly like for every minute. Also, how can we create a script in which it will fetch the log file every minute, analyze its contents and perform some tasks.

Comment: @Death i have updated the question(made it simple, concise and neat) and provided an answer. kindly check. thank you

Comment: this question has been answered, and you marked it as answered! what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to publish it in a web server folder.

By this i mean It is possible to write this file and publish it to either an ftp connection or on the web server itself if you have access to this.

I'll be happy to provide more details if you tell me which way you prefer to go :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to create/write a bash file, cron job or script. The contents will be following the logic : copy the file towards the public web folder every minute.

for client analyzing the log file. one way is to also create a cron job with the following logic: fetch the new log file, then perform analysis (for example, if it found the word "stopped", then some action will be taken like restarting the process/application) and some action. repeat this for every minute